# How to delete lines in a file in Python?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file file that looks like this:

```
people 0.508931508057 -0.280345656093 -0.0318199105583 -0.189979892892 0.00748802665945 -0.0570929853912 0.0688883067716 0.187604694632 0.114414087961 0.150298183734 
well 0.634085165013 -0.130742033765 0.0833007355449 -0.304469830925 0.133714906135 -0.0221626440854 0.062845160898 0.0607120405012 0.0384326647526 -0.0102762686058 
it
 0.451455675985 -0.0309283486444 -0.233415252863 -0.0273732833795 -0.294310277236 0.324236481567 -0.084486587459 0.340305398253 -0.56250445207 0.00640281538272 
but 0.776732251824 0.0216479978956 0.326422159918 0.0654654707123 0.235569019918 0.0792330670559 0.22189299375 0.194232853917 0.102964793215 0.00926554861178 
could 0.505766726467 -0.304640132821 0.015043924871 -0.42831149929 0.13475950648 0.0275223466164 0.154347034425 0.443048319277 0.229038343902 -0.209763506494 
think 0.734314690035 -0.15352368041 0.383964369466 -0.283262375383 0.000534210123265 0.0452656078196 0.0174349360274 -0.0210130687293 0.0247592836651 0.0930452272721 
movie
 0.444291696176 -0.110937149049 -0.259525377532 0.00986849685667 -0.311934727067 0.319610517473 -0.0644468651461 0.372562407 -0.572686043624 0.0262434708424 
made 0.546164908581 -0.148512160184 0.301391306124 -0.553970562504 -0.0423941756245 -0.0789194920559 -0.0336542251386 0.00929984630184 -0.030340761377 -0.112650323493 
way 0.751616772605 -0.345057880564 0.10091886809 -0.147689086912 -0.0721519520719 -0.246317313253 -0.00606560306655 0.0689594126233 0.0468387063595 -0.00900506150062
```

I want to keep in the file only the lines that contain both a word and a set of values on the same line.

How can I delete the rest of them?

The expected output is:

```
people 0.508931508057 -0.280345656093 -0.0318199105583 -0.189979892892 0.00748802665945 -0.0570929853912 0.0688883067716 0.187604694632 0.114414087961 0.150298183734 
well 0.634085165013 -0.130742033765 0.0833007355449 -0.304469830925 0.133714906135 -0.0221626440854 0.062845160898 0.0607120405012 0.0384326647526 -0.0102762686058 
but 0.776732251824 0.0216479978956 0.326422159918 0.0654654707123 0.235569019918 0.0792330670559 0.22189299375 0.194232853917 0.102964793215 0.00926554861178 
could 0.505766726467 -0.304640132821 0.015043924871 -0.42831149929 0.13475950648 0.0275223466164 0.154347034425 0.443048319277 0.229038343902 -0.209763506494 
think 0.734314690035 -0.15352368041 0.383964369466 -0.283262375383 0.000534210123265 0.0452656078196 0.0174349360274 -0.0210130687293 0.0247592836651 0.0930452272721 
made 0.546164908581 -0.148512160184 0.301391306124 -0.553970562504 -0.0423941756245 -0.0789194920559 -0.0336542251386 0.00929984630184 -0.030340761377 -0.112650323493 
way 0.751616772605 -0.345057880564 0.10091886809 -0.147689086912 -0.0721519520719 -0.246317313253 -0.00606560306655 0.0689594126233 0.0468387063595 -0.00900506150062
```

Comment: Are the lines with just values on them always starting with a space?

Comment: yes, they always start with a space

Comment: Does the word always come first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to solve the problem.

1. Read the file as CSV. If the column count is 12 and the first column is not a blank string, write it out:

   ```
   import csv

   with open('original.txt','r') as f, open('new.txt','w') as o:
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
      writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=' ')
      for row in reader:
          if len(row) == 12 and row[0]:
              writer.write(row)
   ```
2. Read the file, write out those lines where the first item is a word and there are more than 2 columns:

   ```
   with open('original.txt', 'r') as f, open('new.txt', 'w') as o:
       for line in f:
          if line.lstrip().split(' ')[0].isalpha() and len(line.split(' ')) > 2:
              o.write(line)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have tried the second method and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this very nicely using the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    if line.find(' ') > 0:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Note that this modifies all the files given on the command line in-place, i.e. they will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and read it line by line. Each line that contains a letter can be copied to another file.

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
letters += letters.upper()

f_in = open("myfile.txt", 'rb')
f_out = open("newfile.txt", 'wb')
for line in f_in:
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in line:
            f_out.write(line)
            break
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Be careful, the example you have given contains only one long line.
This line has to be split into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this gives you the desired result.

```
import re
f = open("i1.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
new_list = []
for items in lines:
    if re.match("[a-zA-Z]+[\s\d]+", items.strip()) or re.match("[\d.\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[\s\d.]*", items.strip()):
        print items.strip()
```

The following is the output

```
people 0.508931508057 -0.280345656093 -0.0318199105583 -0.189979892892 0.00748802665945 -0.0570929853912 0.0688883067716 0.187604694632 0.114414087961 0.150298183734
well 0.634085165013 -0.130742033765 0.0833007355449 -0.304469830925 0.133714906135 -0.0221626440854 0.062845160898 0.0607120405012 0.0384326647526 -0.0102762686058
but 0.776732251824 0.0216479978956 0.326422159918 0.0654654707123 0.235569019918 0.0792330670559 0.22189299375 0.194232853917 0.102964793215 0.00926554861178
could 0.505766726467 -0.304640132821 0.015043924871 -0.42831149929 0.13475950648 0.0275223466164 0.154347034425 0.443048319277 0.229038343902 -0.209763506494
think 0.734314690035 -0.15352368041 0.383964369466 -0.283262375383 0.000534210123265 0.0452656078196 0.0174349360274 -0.0210130687293 0.0247592836651 0.0930452272721
made 0.546164908581 -0.148512160184 0.301391306124 -0.553970562504 -0.0423941756245 -0.0789194920559 -0.0336542251386 0.00929984630184 -0.030340761377 -0.112650323493
way 0.751616772605 -0.345057880564 0.10091886809 -0.147689086912 -0.0721519520719 -0.246317313253 -0.00606560306655 0.0689594126233 0.0468387063595 -0.00900506150062
```

0.34567 yes 0.9876 -0.00606560306655 0.0689594126233 0.0468387063595 -0.00900506150062

Comment: What about the order? May the word come *second*?

Comment: I'm updating the code, this will work if number comes first and the word follows it.